# How to Use do until Loop for the following example?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 reactants in cells `A1:A5` and 10 products in Cells `B1:B10`. The sum of `A1:A5` should be equal to sum of `B1:B10`. The difference of sums for the initial inputs will never match making `sumreactants > sumproducts`. The error fraction is calculated as `(sumreactants-sumproducts)/sumreactants`. This error fraction has to be distributed between `B1:B10` in proportions so that it becomes `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your sum of A1 to A5 is in A11, and sum of B1 to B10 is in B11. To distribute that error (and this is where I think it is a math problem more than an Excel one), would you not just multiply each of B1 to B10 with ratio of (A11/B11)?

See screenshot attached. Values are sample values and proportionate values are calculated in C1:C10. (Hope I understand your Qn correctly, would have asked more in the comments section, but don't have the reputation)
[image: Sample excel for illustration]